# How can I express this recurrence function in Mathematica?

Tags: function-construction, recursion, vector, difference-equations

\begin{equation}
r_{i+1}=r_{i}+V_{i}{\Delta}t
\end{equation}

Where
\begin{equation}
V_{i}=(0.01, 0.40)
\end{equation}
and ${\Delta}t$ is the difference in time.

My implementation (this is for ${\Delta}t$ = 1):

```
V = {0.01, 0.4};
list = List[Do[Print[V*t], {t, 1, 10}]];

* $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. *
```

This generates the correct values but I can't change ${\Delta}t$ and the values aren't stored as a list (for use with ListPlot[...]).

I have tried other implementations such as `r[t_]=r[t]+V*t` and `r[t_+1]=r[t]+V*t` but this didn't work.

Comment: I would suggest using `RecurrenceTable` - it's designed for this purpose, but sadly it doesn't support vector-valued recurrence equations as gracefully as it should...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
v = {0.01, 0.4};
```

you can define

```
r[n_, dt_] := r[n, dt] = r[n - 1, dt] + v dt
r[0, dt_] = {0, 0}
```

Now

```
Table[r[n, 1], {n, 1, 10}]
```

> ```
> {{0.01, 0.4}, {0.02, 0.8}, {0.03, 1.2}, {0.04, 1.6}, {0.05, 2.}, {0.06, 2.4}, {0.07, 2.8}, 
>  {0.08, 3.2}, {0.09, 3.6}, {0.1, 4.}}
> ```

and

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Table[r[n, deltat], {n, 1, 10}], PlotRange -> 20],
 {{deltat, 1, "Δt"}, 0, 5}]
```

> [image: Manipulate]

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `NestList`:

```
tbl[v_, delta_, n_, init_: {0, 0}] := NestList[# + v delta &, init, n]

tbl[v, 1, 10]
(* {{0, 0}, {0.01, 0.4}, {0.02, 0.8}, {0.03, 1.2}, {0.04, 1.6}, 
    {0.05, 2.}, {0.06, 2.4}, {0.07, 2.8}, {0.08, 3.2}, {0.09, 3.6}, {0.1, 4.}} *)
```